# Why is BigInteger in C# a struct if it has an unbounded size?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Why is BigInteger declared as a ValueType (struct) in C#? It seems to be very similar to the string type which is declared as a reference type.

Both are immutable (value types). Both can be arbitrarily large.

The recommendation I have heard is that a struct should never be more than 16 Bytes. BigInteger can get much larger than 16 Bytes and I would think this would make frequent operations extremely slow since it is always copied by value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying a BigInteger does not cause the underlying data to be copied. Instead, just a reference to the data is copied.

Since BigInteger values are immutable it is safe for two or more values to share a common data buffer.

BigInteger has two instance fields:

- `int _sign` - probably tells whether its a positive or negative value.
- `uint[] _bits` - this is a reference to the data buffer.

An `int` is 4 bytes and a reference is 8 bytes (on a 64-bit system). Therefore the size of a BigInteger is ≤ 16 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [the source for BigInteger](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs) and strip it down to only instance level fields (the things that would count toward it's size) all the class has is

```
public struct BigInteger : IFormattable, IComparable, IComparable<BigInteger>, IEquatable<BigInteger>                             
{
    internal int _sign;
    internal uint[] _bits;
}
```

So you have 4 bytes for `_sign` and 4 or 8 bytes for `uint[]` depending on if you are on a 32 or 64 bit system due to the fact that arrays are reference types. This gives you a total of 8 or 12 bytes, well below the 16 recommendation. (note: The CLR will pad the 12 byte version to 16 to make it a multiple of 8 for optimization reasons)

When a new BigInteger is created the `_bits` array will be shared between the two instances. Because the type is immutable (you can't change the value of any cell of `_bits`) it is safe for the two copies to share the array.

Comment: Can you explain why you only count the memory size for the `uint[]` rather than the length of the elements it contains? If its arbitrarily large, it could have more than 1 or 2 elements making it bigger than 8 bytes. If you are only counting the reference, thats important to note I think when counting size.

Comment: @RonBeyer [arrays are classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) not value types, so no matter how large the array is the `_bits` variable only uses `sizeof(IntPtr)` memory to store the reference. It also uses `sizeof(uint) * _bits.Length` memory to hold the data, but that data is stored on the heap and is not counted toward the size of the struct and is not copied when you make a copy of the struct.

Comment: I understand that arrays are reference types, I was hoping you'd add to your answer the part about how the struct owns the reference to the data, not necessarily the data itself, since that is a harder concept to grab.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the fields of a `BigInteger`:

```
// For values int.MinValue < n <= int.MaxValue, the value is stored in sign
// and _bits is null. For all other values, sign is +1 or -1 and the bits are in _bits
internal int _sign;
internal uint[] _bits;
```

So, one `int` and one `uint[]`, which is a reference type. The type itself can't grow arbitrarily large. It'll be 8 bytes on x86 and 16 bytes on x64 (12 bytes for the field + 4 bytes of padding).

`string` and arrays are the only types in the framework which have a varying size and are special-cased in the runtime.

As to answer the question: there is less overhead in using a `struct`. Having a `class` wrapper over two fields would cause more indirection and more GC pressure for no good reason. Besides, a `BigInteger` is *semantically* a value.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a struct matters only because the entire struct has to be copied each time you pass it around from one function to another.  If it was not for the copying, nobody would care.

However, `BigInteger` consists of two parts:

- The actual struct, which is the part that gets copied when you pass a `BigInteger` around, and is fairly small, and
- The array of bits, which is of arbitrary length, but which is ***not*** copied each time the struct is copied.

So, when you pass a `BigInteger`, this is what happens:

Before copying:

```
[BigInteger instance 1] ---------> [array of bits]
```

After copying:

```
[BigInteger instance 1] ---------> [array of bits]
                            |
[BigInteger instance 2] ----+
```

Notice how there is always just one array of bits.